# Write a function GeneratePassword which accepts two arguments, an integer and a character string consisting of letters (a-z) and digits (0-9)

Tags: php

Write a function `GeneratePassword` which accepts two arguments, an integer and a character string consisting of letters (a-z) and digits (0-9).

When `GeneratePassword(5,'abc0123')` is called, it should return a random string of 5 characters taken from 'abc0123'.

For Example : `GeneratePassword(7,'abczxc012394')` could return any of the following outputs :

> 2c00acb
>   2c23z93
>   030b2a4

Comment: And it would be really nice of the asker to actually award a vote up and click the checkmark to accept Brad's answer...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag.

In the spirit of helping others I'll post a commented solution. However, keep in mind the only way to get better is to **try first, ask questions later**. That is to say, make an attempt then ask others where you went wrong.

Example/[Demo](http://ideone.com/4oRB0):

```
/**
 * Generate a password N characters long consisting of characters
 *
 * @param int $size
 * @param string $characters
 * @param callback $random (optional) source of random, a function with two parameters, from and to
 * @return string|NULL password
 */
function generate_password($size, $characters, $random = 'rand') {

    // validate $size input
    $size = (int) $size;

    if ($size <= 0) {
        trigger_error(sprintf('Can not create a password of size %d. [%s]', $size, __FUNCTION__), E_USER_WARNING);
        return NULL;
    }

    if ($size > 255) {
        trigger_error(sprintf('Refused to create a password of size %d as this is larger than 255. [%s]', $size, __FUNCTION__), E_USER_WARNING);
        return NULL;
    }

    // normalize $characters input, remove duplicate characters
    $characters = count_chars($characters, 3);

    // validate number of characters
    $length = strlen($characters);
    if ($length < 1) {
        trigger_error(sprintf('Can not create a random password out of %d character(s). [%s]', $length, __FUNCTION__), E_USER_WARNING);
        return NULL;
    }

    // initialize the password result
    $password = str_repeat("\x00", $size);

    // get the number of characters minus one
    // your string of characters actually begins at 0 and ends on the
    // string-length - 1:
    //   $characters[0] = 'a'
    //   $characters[1] = 'b'
    //   $characters[2] = 'c'
    $length--;

    // get one random character per each place in the password
    while ($size--)
    {
        // generate a random number between 0 and $length (including)
        $randomValue = $random(0, $length);
        // that random number is used to turn the number into a character
        $character = $characters[$randomValue];
        // set the random character
        $password[$size] = $character;
    }

    // return the result
    return $password;
}
```